# Interruption of "read_until" in Python serial package

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port

I have a serial port listener, which reads until a specific string. It will run on a Pi remotely with limited access, so I wanted to ask if there is a way to send a notification in case the read_until get's stuck due to a corrupted message with a faulty ending?
Here is a part of my code:

```
def serial_connection(port_connected):
    try:
        serial_connection_port = serial.Serial(
            port = port_connected,
            baudrate = 500000,
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
            timeout = None,
            )

    except serial.SerialException:
        logging.error(serial.SerialException)
        raise serial.SerialException

    return serial_connection_port
```

and the continuation which is inside a thread, since I'm listening to 4 serial ports simultaneously:

```
while True:
        message_raw = serial_message_reader(serial_connection_port)
```

```
def serial_message_reader(serial_connection_port):
    try:
        message = serial_connection_port.read_until(b'_A5A5')
        return message
    except:
        print(f'Error in serial_message_reader function on port {serial_connection_port.name}. Sleep for 1 second')     # send notification: Unable to read message
        time.sleep(1)
```

Is there a way to play around with the timeout and send a notification in case we reached it?
The messages should come in an Interval of 1-4 seconds each.
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to, but you can use the built-in asyncio module to wait for your function, example:

```
import asyncio

async def serial_message_reader(serial_connection_port):
    try:
        message = await asyncio.wait_for(serial_connection_port.read_until(b'_A5A5'), timeout=10)
        return message
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print(f"Timed out trying to read_until")
    except:
        print(f'Error in serial_message_reader function on port {serial_connection_port.name}. Sleep for 1 second')     # send notification: Unable to read message
        time.sleep(1)
```

If it reaches the timeout, then a asyncio.TimeoutError is raised. 'timeout=' at the end is in seconds.

Please note: you have to await the function serial_message_reader:

`test = await serial_message_reader(serial_connection_port)`

Comment: This looks quite nice. I'll try if it's working in my case and if it won't cause problems with the threading. Thanks